# Select option value add to querystring

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I get the value of a selected option value and put in into url querystring

```
<td><select name="rate" id="rating" class="form-control col-sm-4">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
<td><a href="server.php?rate_id='.$table["rating_id"].'?r='[I want to put it here]' " class="btn btn-info" >Rate</td>
```

I tried using function but putting it in, cause wrong syntax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rating').on('change', get_value_rate);
});

function get_value_rate() {
    var selected = $('#rating').val();
    return selected;
}
```

I use alert() function and It get the value but after putting do_something() on query string it doesn't work 'return' syntax error as said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it with plain JavaScript.

You can use the `querySelector()` function to query elements in the DOM and get the select value, build the `url` using template strings and then set the `href` attribute on your anchor tag.

You can attach the event listener in HTML:

```
<select ... onchange="onChange()">
```

Or using the `addEventListener()` function:

```
select.addEventListener('change', onChange);
```

Here is the MDN doc on [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

If you want to bind the rating id from php, I suggest to bind a `data` attribute on the link and later use that attribute to construct the href from JavaScript.
I named this attribute `data-rating-id` and it can be set like this with PHP:

```
<a href="#" data-rating-id="<?php echo $table["rating_id"] ?>">Rate</a>
```

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#rating');
const link = document.querySelector('#link');
const ratingId = link.getAttribute('data-rating-id');

// Attach the event handler
select.addEventListener('change', onChange);

// Set the initial href for the link
setRateLink(select.value);

// Event handler
function onChange() {
  setRateLink(select.value);
}

// Function to generate URL and set href
function setRateLink(value) {
  const href = `server.php?rate_id=${ratingId}?r=${value}`;
  link.href = href;
  console.log(`href is "${href}"`);
}
```

```html
<select name="rate" id="rating" class="form-control col-sm-4">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<a id='link' href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-rating-id="123">Rate</a>
```

Comment: I add [rating_id] of data-id attribute of select so i can display it also because it says that rate_id is unidentified and it works , but just asking about the code const table = {}; cause i got confused. Sorry :(

Comment: yes sorry, I removed that code when I saw it was set from php. This is why I added the data attribute, so you can set the href while keeping the value set form php in the template

Answer (score 0):

use jquery and get the value of a selected option value and put in into url

```
<td><select name="rate" id="rating" class="form-control col-sm-4">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-info"  id ="link">Rate</a></td>
```

$("#rating").change(function(){

val = $(this).val();

$("#link").attr("href", "server.php?rate_id="+val);

})